# Insert String into String C#

Tags: c#, string, insert

Hi I have a string of XML and im looking to insert another block of XML in a specific location using C#.

> < Test >
>      < group>
>       < /group>
>       < group>
>        < /group>
>   < /Test>
>    < Lol >
>    < group>
>        < /group>
>   < /Lol>

I want to insert a string after the last < /group> inside < Test>so that it looks like

> < Test >
>      < group>
>       < /group>
>       < group>
>        < /group>
>       < i added this group>
>        < /i added this group>
>   < /Test>
>    < Lol >
>    < group>
>        < /group>
>   < /Lol>

If anyone knows how to do this please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

the string is not just of a single element but potentially hundreds of elements and sub elements and sub sub elements and many different attributes. elementception
THIS IS A SAMPLE STRING SIMILAR TO HOW addme WOULD LOOK:

```
<Group Id="Customers" ResourceId="Group_Customers" DescriptionResourceId="Customers_Description">
  <SubArea Id="nav_accts" DescriptionResourceId="Account_SubArea_Description" Entity="account" GetStartedPanePath="Accounts_Web_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Accounts_Web_Admin_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Accounts_Outlook_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Accounts_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" />
  <SubArea Id="nav_conts" DescriptionResourceId="Contact_SubArea_Description" Entity="contact" GetStartedPanePath="Contacts_Web_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Contacts_Web_Admin_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Contacts_Outlook_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Contacts_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" />
</Group>
<Group Id="SFA" ResourceId="Area_Sales" DescriptionResourceId="Sales_Description">
  <SubArea Id="nav_leads" DescriptionResourceId="Lead_SubArea_Description" Entity="lead" GetStartedPanePath="Leads_Web_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Leads_Web_Admin_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Leads_Outlook_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Leads_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" />
  <SubArea Id="nav_oppts" DescriptionResourceId="Opportunity_SubArea_Description" Entity="opportunity" GetStartedPanePath="Opportunities_Web_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Opportunities_Web_Admin_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Opportunities_Outlook_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Opportunities_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" />
  <SubArea Id="nav_comps" DescriptionResourceId="Competitor_SubArea_Description" Entity="competitor" />
</Group>
<Group Id="Collateral" ResourceId="Area_Collateral" DescriptionResourceId="Area_Collateral_Description">
  <SubArea Id="nav_quotes" DescriptionResourceId="Quote_SubArea_Description" Entity="quote" GetStartedPanePath="Quotes_Web_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Quotes_Web_Admin_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Quotes_Outlook_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Quotes_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" />
  <SubArea Id="nav_orders" DescriptionResourceId="Orders_SubArea_Description" Entity="salesorder" GetStartedPanePath="Orders_Web_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Orders_Web_Admin_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Orders_Outlook_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Orders_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" />
  <SubArea Id="nav_invoices" DescriptionResourceId="Invoice_SubArea_Description" Entity="invoice" GetStartedPanePath="Invoices_Web_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Invoices_Web_Admin_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Invoices_Outlook_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Invoices_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" />
  <SubArea Id="nav_products" DescriptionResourceId="Product_SubArea_Description" Entity="product" GetStartedPanePath="Products_Web_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Products_Web_Admin_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Products_Outlook_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Products_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" />
  <SubArea Id="nav_saleslit" DescriptionResourceId="SalesLit_SubArea_Description" Entity="salesliterature" />
</Group>
<Group Id="MA" ResourceId="Area_Marketing" DescriptionResourceId="Marketing_Description">
  <SubArea Id="nav_lists" DescriptionResourceId="MarketingList_SubArea_Description" Entity="list" GetStartedPanePath="Marketing-Lists_Web_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Marketing-Lists_Web_Admin_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Marketing-Lists_Outlook_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Marketing-Lists_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" />
  <SubArea Id="nav_minicamps" DescriptionResourceId="Quick_Campaign_Description" Icon="/_imgs/ico_18_minicamps.gif" Entity="bulkoperation" GetStartedPanePath="Quick-Campaigns_Web_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Quick-Campaigns_Web_Admin_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Quick-Campaigns_Outlook_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Quick-Campaigns_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" OutlookShortcutIcon="/_imgs/olk_4400.ico">
    <Privilege Privilege="AllowQuickCampaign" />
  </SubArea>
</Group>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what specific problem are you having?  There are many answers on SO about XML parsing/modification as well as string operations.

Comment: int index = xml.IndexOf("</SiteMap>");
               string go = xml.Insert(index + "</SiteMap>".Length, addme);

Comment: Don't use string operations to modify XML. Load it into an `XElement`.

Comment: I have a block of XML with multiple elements inside it as a string. is there anyway to generate that and add it to a XDocument

I tried this and it didn't work:

sitemapxml.Root.Element("Area").LastNode.AddAfterSelf(addme);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this , first load the string as xml

```
   string xmlContent = "Your xml string content";
   //parse the string as xml
   XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
   //get the element which matches your need.
   XElement areaElement = 
       (from el in xmlDoc.Descendants("area") where el.Attribute("id").Value=="workplace"
       select el).FirstOrDefault();
   //create a new group element
   XElement newGroup = new XElement("i added this group");
   //add a value for this element or add attributes what ever is needed to this group here
   //add the new group this will by default add it at the end of all other child elements.
   areaElement.Add(newGroup);
```

Comment: +1 for treating an XML string as **XML** instead of as a string. The format and API exist for a reason. :)

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have been more clear. the string would look more like this: its not 1 element its many elements and many sub elements.
<Group Id="Customers" ResourceId="Group_Customers" DescriptionResourceId="Customers_Description">
<SubArea Id="nav_accts" DescriptionResourceId="Account_SubArea_Description" Entity="account" GetStartedPanePath="Accounts_Web_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Accounts_Web_Admin_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Accounts_Outlook_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Accounts_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" /></Group>
but like way longer haha

Comment: Your group element can have any number of attributes or subelements but that doesn't matter if you just need to create another element at the end of area element (i.e adding a new group as sibling of other group element which is inside the area element) . Still if you couldn't get it then please post the exact xml and the element which you want to add so that we can post the complete example , but at least i expect , you should try that :( since most of the skeleton is already given.

Comment: ah yes well the xml is dynamic. so id have to dynamically generate the areas and attributes that is more the problem. is there anyway to just append an xdocument afterwards.

Comment: im using javascript to parse a zip file extract a specific portion of xml from a file and return it as a string. i then have a plugin that will recieve this xml string and append it to already existing xml.

Comment: right now i just append the string and convert it into an xdocument that way.

Comment: You cant append XDocument to an XElement , what you can do is get the root element from XDocument (documentObject.Root where documentObject is instance of the type XDocument) and append it to element which you would like to do.

Comment: You can change the existing line XElement newGroup = new XElement("i added this group"); to XElement newGroup = XDocument.Load("someotherxmlstring").Root;

Comment: ahh ok yeah thats all i needed to know thank you!

Comment: Oops i made a mistake in the last comment , it should be  XElement newGroup = XDocument.Parse("someotherxmlstring").Root; Sorry if this had confused you . Glad that you could solve your problem :)